The trace of a matrix and the radical ideal generated by its power
Consider the polynomial ring $ \mathbb{C}[x_{11}, \dots , x_{nn}] $ with $ n^2 $ variables and the matrix
$$  
A := 
\begin{pmatrix}
  x_{11} & \cdots & x_{1n} \\
  \vdots & & \vdots \\
  x_{n1} & \cdots & x_{nn}
 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let $ m \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} $, and define polynomials $ f_{11}, \dots, f_{nn} \in \mathbb{C}[x_{11}, \dots, x_{nn}] $ by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  f_{11} & \cdots & f_{1n} \\
  \vdots & & \vdots \\
  f_{n1} & \cdots & f_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
:=
A^m.
$$
Let $ I := (f_{11}, \dots ,f_{nn}) $, which is the ideal generated by $ f_{11}, \dots, f_{nn} $ in $ \mathbb{C}[x_{11}, \dots,x_{nn}] $. One can easily show that:
$$  
\operatorname{tr}(A) \in \operatorname{rad}(f_{11}, \dots ,f_{nn}).
$$
For example, one may use Hilbert's Nullstellsatz to prove it. First we have:
$$
\operatorname{rad}(f_{11}, \dots ,f_{nn}) = \mathcal{I} \circ \mathcal{Z}(f_{11}, \dots, f_{nn}).
$$
For each $ a \in \mathbb{A}^n $,
$$
a \in \mathcal{Z}(f_{11}, \dots, f_{nn}) 
\iff
A^m(a) = A(a)^m = 0,
$$
which implies that $ \operatorname{tr}(A(a)) = \operatorname{tr}(A)(a) = 0 $. Thus $ \operatorname{tr}(A) $ vanishes on $ \mathcal{Z}(f_{11}, \dots, f_{nn}) $, hence belongs to $ \mathcal{I} \circ \mathcal{Z}(f_{11}, \dots, f_{nn}) = \operatorname{rad}(f_{11}, \dots ,f_{nn}) $. QED.
That is to say, there exists some $ N \in \mathbb{Z}_+ $, such that:
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A)^N \in I.
$$
My question is that: What is the minimal $ N $?
I calculated some examples:



The minimal $ N $
$ m = 1 $
$ m = 2 $
$ m = 3 $
$ m = 4 $
$ m = 5 $
$ m = 6 $
$ m = 7 $
$ m = 8 $
$ m = 9 $
$ m = 10 $
$ m = 11 $




$ n = 2 $
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21


$ n = 3 $
1
4
7
10









$ n = 4 $
1
5












These are all the examples that I can work out with my PC. My own conjecture is that
$$
N = n(m - 1) + 1.
$$
Evidently, it is an extremely complicated problem but I am really interested in it. I searched over the Internet for a long time but found nothing useful. I wonder if there is any background for this problem and any related research on it.
Thank you for taking time to read.

This is a question about the so called generic matrices. Somebody with a background in polynomial identity rings might help you.

Which software have you used for computing your results ?

@JeanMarie Wolfram Mathematica.
